# Firebase client on ReactNative

Tags: firebase, reactjs, react-native

When using Firebase on ReactNative, it will show such error message:

> can't find variable process

However, if I require `firebase/lib/firebase-web.js` manually, it will show:

> can't find variable document

How can I resolve this?

Comment: You can solve by doing what Jason did here: https://github.com/badfortrains/wsExample You might want to follow along with the discussion here: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/firebase-talk/aoPNvQQsVUE

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just figuring it our. Pavan's answer is helpful, but it is not quite true when using with Firebase.

For firebase, please follow the steps:

1. Download the `firebase-debug.js` from [wsExample](https://github.com/badfortrains/wsExample). Or you can just install wsExample by npm and require the `firebase-debug.js` inside it.
2. Use badfortrains's forked React-Native:

   ```
   "react-native": "git://github.com/badfortrains/react-native#WebSocket"
   ```
3. New the Firebase like this:

   ```
   var firebase = require("../../firebase-debug.js");
   var rootRef = new Firebase(Const.FB_ROOT);
   ```

Things should just work now!

Answer (score 4):

I just went through the same issue while trying to use sockets.io in my react native app so hopefully I can help.

The reason that you cannot use firebase's node module is because there hasn't been a polyfill created yet for websockets support (which firebase is dependent on) in react native.

If you take a look at [issue #619](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/619) in react native's repo you'll find the current discussion on creating a websockets api polyfill.

The way that we solved it is by using Jason's modified version of the sockets library and creating [our own repo](https://github.com/crewapp/react-native-sockets-io) around just that file. Then we added the line below to our package.json dependencies.

```
"react-sockets": "crewapp/react-native-sockets-io"
```

[image]

The reason that Jason's version of the sockets.io client file works is because react-native is added as a user agent. You can find the code that makes this change at the top of the file:

```
window.navigator = {
  userAgent: "react-native"
}
```

Once you've gone through these steps you should be able to require [sockets.io](http://socket.io) / [firebase](https://www.firebase.com) as normal.

Comment: So is this using firebase-web?

Answer (score 0):

I had issues with socket.io on React Native too, solution was to get notifications about new data and if data is big enough - get it by simple RESTfull request. in my case data was small enough   to be sent all within notifications API.

I was using GCM service to send notification to phone from nodejs server. BTW, it uses less battery then socket connection and works great :)